# How to rewrite a Awk script to process several files instead of one

Tags: awk, report, xargs

I am writing a report tool which processes the source files of some application and produce a report table with two columns, one containing the name of the file and the other containing the word `TODO` if the file contains a call to some deprecated function `deprecated_function` and `DONE` otherwise.

I used `awk` to prepare this report and my shell script looks like

```
report()
{
  find . -type f -name '*.c' \
    | xargs -n 1 awk -v deprecated="$1" '
BEGIN { status = "DONE" }
$0 ~ deprecated{ status = "TODO" }
END {
  printf("%s|%s\n", FILENAME, status)
}'
}
report "deprecated_function"
```

The output of this script looks like

```
./plop-plop.c|DONE
./fizz-boum.c|TODO
```

This works well but I would like to rewrite the `awk` script so that it supports several input files instead of just one — so that I can remove the `-n 1` argument to `xargs`.  The only solutions I could figure out involve a lot of bookkeeping, because we need to track the changes of `FILENAME` and the `END` event to catch each *end of file event*.

```
awk -v deprecated="$1" '
BEGIN { status = "DONE" }
oldfilename && (oldfilename != FILENAME) {
  printf("%s|%s\n", oldfilename, status);
  status = DONE;
  oldfilename = FILENAME;
}
$0 ~ deprecated{ status = "TODO" }
END {
  printf("%s|%s\n", FILENAME, status)
}'
```

Maybe there is a cleaner and shorter way to handle this.

*I am using FreeBSD's `awk` and am looking for solutions compatible with this tool.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work in any modern awk:

```
awk -v deprecated="$1" -v OFS='|' '
    $0 ~ deprecated{ dep[FILENAME] }
    END {
        for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++)
            print ARGV[i], (ARGV[i] in dep ? "TODO" : "DONE")
    }
' file1 file2 ...
```

Any time you need to produce a report for all files and don't have GNU awk for ENDFILE, you MUST loop through ARGV[] in the END section (or loop through it in BEGIN and populate a different array for END section processing). Anything else will fail if you have empty files.

Comment: This *is* an improvement!  Thank you for your insight!

Comment: +1 for avoiding the repetition and ensuring that no input = no output

Answer (score 1):

Your awk script could be something like this:

```
awk -v deprecated="$1" '
FNR==1 {if(file) print file "|" (f?"TODO":"DONE"); file=FILENAME; f=0}
$0 ~ deprecated {f=1} 
END {print file "|" (f?"TODO":"DONE")}' file1.c file2.c # etc.
```

The logic is fairly similar to your program so hopefully it's all clear. `FNR` is the record number of the current file, which I'm using to detect the start of a new file. Admittedly there's some repetition in the `END` block but I don't think it's a big deal. You could always use a function if you wanted to.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat f1.c
int deprecated_function()
{
    // some deprecated stuff
}
$ cat f2.c 
int good_function() 
{
    // some good stuff
}
$ find -name "f?.c" -print0 | xargs -0 awk -v deprecated="deprecated" 'FNR==1 {if(file) print file "|" (f?"TODO":"DONE"); file=FILENAME; f=0} $0 ~ deprecated {f=1} END {print file "|" (f?"TODO":"DONE")}'
./f2.c|DONE
./f1.c|TODO
```

I have used `-print0` and the `-0` switch to xargs so that both programs with work file names separated by null bytes "\0" rather than spaces. This means that you won't run into problems with spaces in file names.

Comment: This is pretty similar to my own solution because it needs to keep track of `FILENAME` changes and monitor the `END`… so it seems that there is no real way to avoid this.  For the `-0` thing, we are consistently sending our people using spaces in source file names to the taxidermy department, but the remark might be useful for the casual reader.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to avoid it with your version of awk. If you were using GNU awk, I would have suggested using `ENDFILE`...I've just edited it to cut the length down a little bit more. I'm sure there's more that could be done, although perhaps it would be at the expense of readability.

Comment: Note that `deprecated` is a variable so you can't use it within a regexp literal.

Comment: @Ed thanks, I've edited. Point taken from your comment above that this will still produce output if no files are passed to it.

Comment: @TomFenech and it won't produce any output for each empty file passed to it and if the last file is empty, it'll produce a report for the 2nd-last file twice, etc... Unfortunately without gawk+ENDFILE you just can't do this type of job without a loop on files in the END section which is why gawk has ENDFILE.